# 1and1.com forward domain name to my sftp server

Tags: dns

Hi we have a domain name mysite.net registered on 1and1.com. We also have an SFTP server set up. How do we set up DNS so the user can use mysite.net to access the SFTP server?

Currently the DNS settings are:

> Name server settings: we use 1&1 name servers.
>
> A records: we use "Other IP address"
>
> IPv4 Address: we filled in the IP address for the SFTP server

After the 1and1 server updated, the sftp server still can't be accessed by using mysite.net. And when I ping mysite.net it returned a different IP address (a website called sedo domain parking).

Do we need to create a subdomain, like sftp.mysite.net?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you also running a website, or email, or anything else from the domain besides SFTP?